# Кастомные методы

Tags: java

Что такое кастомные методы, в частности в java?
Например, кастомный метод добавления значения в List

Comment: Уточните более детально что вас интересует. Вопрос относиться к паттернам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кастомный метод (custom method) или же метод, определяемый пользователем (user-defined method) обозначает практически любой метод, создаваемый прикладным программистом (пользователем) с целью реализации требуемой функциональности, в отличие от методов, реализованных в самой Java (JDK), "стандартных" библиотеках / фреймворках, и, возможно, в виде бойлерплейтного кода в виде геттеров/сеттеров.

Если требуется разработать *"кастомный метод добавления значения в `List`"*, для начала следует ознакомиться с интерфейсом [`java.util.List` хотя бы для Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html), и убедиться, что этот интерфейс предоставляет как минимум два метода для добавления значения:

- [`boolean add(E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-), *[унаследованный](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add-E-) из интерфейса `Collection`*, который добавляет элемент в конец данного списка
- [`void add(int index, E e)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-), который *вставляет* элемент в заданную позицию `index` в списке, сдвигая существующий элемент списка (если такой есть) и все последующие вправо на одну позицию.

Также есть пара соответствующих методов для добавления *коллекций* [`List::addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-), [`List::addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-int-java.util.Collection-)

То есть, вроде бы уже есть всё готовое, и кастомизировать особо нечего.

Но предположим, что зачем-то понадобилось расширить существующий интерфейс, добавив некие синонимы для указанных методов `append` и `insertAt`.  Тогда в новом интерфейсе можно сразу же предоставить реализации "новых" методов, используя дефолтные методы в интерфейсах:

```java
import java.util.List;

public interface MyList<E> extends List<E> {
    default void append(E e) {
        add(e);
    }

    default void insertAt(int index, E e) {
        add(index, e);
    }
}
```

Однако, чтобы данные методы-синонимы можно было использовать в *конкретных реализациях* вроде `ArrayList`, потребуется также создать собственную реализацию, переопределив нужные конструкторы:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class MyArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> implements MyList<E> {
    public MyArrayList() { super();}
    public MyArrayList(int capacity) { super(capacity);}
    public MyArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) { super(c);}
}
```

Использование:

```
MyList<String> myList = new MyArrayList<>(List.of("foo", "bar"));
myList.append("baz");
```

---

Другой пример кастомной реализации: добавление элементов в случайном порядке, тогда фактически будет переопределяться реализация существующего метода `add` в конкретном классе, которая также сведётся к вызову метода родительского класса:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class RandomArrayList<E> extends ArrayList<E> {
    private Random rand = new Random();

    public RandomArrayList() { super();}
    public RandomArrayList(int capacity) { super(capacity);}
    public RandomArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) { 
        super(c);
        Collections.shuffle(this, rand);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        super.add(rand.nextInt(size()), e);
        return true;
    }
}
```